# Sum of manipulated geometric series

Tags: analysis, summation, power-series, geometric-series

Find the sum of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{2^n}$$
I know I need to manipulate the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$ with $x = \frac{1}{2}$, but I'm not sure how. Would differentiating it twice help?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593996/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-6/594019#594019

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{2^n} = 6$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593996/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-6)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Considering $$S=\sum_{i=1}^\infty n^2 x^n=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (n^2-n+n) x^n=\sum_{i=1}^\infty n(n-1) x^n+\sum_{i=1}^\infty n x^n$$ $$S=x^2\sum_{i=1}^\infty n(n-1) x^{n-2}+x\sum_{i=1}^\infty n x^{n-1}$$ $$S=x^2\left( \sum_{i=1}^\infty  x^{n}\right)''+x\left( \sum_{i=1}^\infty  x^{n}\right)'$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

If $S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$, then

$$x(xS'(x))'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2x^n$$

Then, let $x=\frac12$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark