# Using power series, calculate the sum of this series $\sum_{n\ge0}{{\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{3^n}}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How do I calculate this sum, using power series? $$\sum_{n\ge0}{{\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{3^n}}}$$
I want just some hints to get me on the right track

Comment: Looks the the second derivative of a power series in x evaluated at 1.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593996/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$(n+2)(n+1)x^n$$

is the second derivative of $x^{n+2}$.
Therefore,

$$\sum_{n \ge 0} (n+2)(n+1)x^n \tag{1}$$

is the second derivative of
$$
\sum_{n \ge 0} x^{n+2} = \frac{x^2}{1-x}. \tag{2}
$$

See if you can use (2) to get a closed form for (1). Then plug in a specific value of $x$.

Comment: I got it, thx a lot.