# Computing $\sum_{n=1}^ \infty n^2 \cdot \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been dealing with the following series for a while now, without real progress.

$$\sum_{n=1}^ \infty n^2 \cdot \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$$

After using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20(n%5E2)*(2%2F3)%5En%20from%201%20to%20infinity), I know it converges to $30$, but I can't see how to calculate it by myself.

Any leads would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's one more naive method other than good answer already given, i was talking about denoting it as S and subtracting from it 2 thirds of S. Again repeating similar step. It requires sum to be convergent

Comment: @KingTut Do you mean to repeat the subtraction infinitely?

Comment: No, I said twice.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/594008/520782

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac1{1-x}$ (if $|x|<1$). Then$$f''(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)x^{n-2}=\frac1{x^2}\left(\sum_{n=2}^\infty n^2x^n-\sum_{n=2}^\infty nx^n\right).$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Should (n^2)(x^2) be (n^2)(x^n)? Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @GalAbra I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For $-1<x<1$, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{k}x^n=\frac{x(1-x^{k})}{1-x}$.

Differentiating,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^knx^{n-1}&=\frac{(1-x)[1-(k+1)x^k]-(x-x^{k+1})(-1)}{(1-x)^2}\\
&=\frac{1-(k+1)x^k+kx^{k+1}}{(1-x)^2}\\
\end{align*}

So.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^knx^{n}&=\frac{(1-x)[1-(k+1)x^k]-(x-x^{k+1})(-1)}{(1-x)^2}\\
&=\frac{x-(k+1)x^{k+1}+kx^{k+2}}{(1-x)^2}\\
\end{align*}

Then differentiate again and multiply by $x$. Put $x=\frac{2}{3}$. Take $k\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $2/3$ by a variable $x$. Then the series defined by

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2 x^k$$

converges locally uniformly for $|x|<1$, hence we can integrate and differentiate it termwise so

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2 x^k=x\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2 x^{k-1}=x\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\frac{d}{dx}( x^k)=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^k\right)\\=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\sum_{k=1}^\infty k x^{k-1}\right)=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{d}{dx}(x^k)\right)=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k\right)=\left[x\frac{d}{dx}\right]^2\frac{x}{1-x}\\=\left[x\frac{d}{dx}\right]\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=x\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{2x}{(1-x)^3}\right)=\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}$$

Hence

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2(2/3)^k=\left[\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2 x^k\right]_{x=2/3}=\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}\bigg|_{x=2/3}=\frac{10}9\cdot 3^3=3\cdot 10=30$$

Answer (score 1):

- Observe that $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=(1-x)^{-1}$ if $|x|<1$
- On both sides take the derivative: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}=(1-x)^{-2}$
- Again on both sides take the derivative: $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)x^{n-2}=2(1-x)^{-3}$

Based on the LHS summations you can find an expression for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2x^n$ and substitute $x=\frac23$.

I leave that to you.