# Which infinite series is this - $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{p}x^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, uniform-convergence

A Series is given $$f_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{p}x^n$$, where $a \in (0,1), \forall p>0$. We have to show that the $f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent on $[-a,a]$

From here, I get $$1^p x+2^p x^2+3^px^3+.....\infty$$   I know this series is uniformly convergent in the given interval where $\limsup_{n \to \infty}a^n \longrightarrow 0, x[-a,a]\subset (0,1)$

Now I'am stuck here. I cannot show $M_n$ from the series as I cannot reduce this in a particular format.

Anybody knows in which form of series this can be reduced? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593996/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-6

Comment: A lengthy process. How to show $M_n$ for the series.

Comment: Showing the series is uniformly convergent on $[-a,a]$ is much easier than evaluating the partial sums.  Use the Weierstrass $M$-test, $|n^p x^n| \le n^p a^n$, and the root test.

Comment: @GEdgar, would you like to clear my two confusions? Is it everytime necessary that the $M_n$ , determined from a series must be of $\frac{1}{n^p}, p>1$ form? and following your suggestion if $|n^px^n| \leq n^pa^n$ and then if we take root test it won't be of the form $\sum\frac{1}{n^p}$. Is $n^pa^n$ correct to consider as $M_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof of uniform convergence, without evaluating the partial sum.

Let $p>0$ and $0<a<1$.  We claim the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{p}x^n
\tag{1}
$$
converges uniformly on $[-a,a]$.

Indeed, for any $x \in [-a,a]$, we have
$$
|n^p x^n| \le n^p a^n .
$$
The series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^p a^n
$$
converges by the root test: as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\big(n^p a^n\big)^{1/n} = (n^{1/n})^p \cdot a \to 1^p\cdot a = a < 1 .
$$
Thus, by the [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test), series (1) converges uniformly on $[-a,a]$.

Comment: I did the same thing but was still confused. Thank you for your great effort. It is now clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

If $|x|<1$ the general expression for the sum is:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^n x^k=\frac{x\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}A(n-1,l)x^l}{(1-x)^{n+1}},
$$
where $A(n-1,l)$ are the [Eulerian numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number). Can be proved by induction.

Comment: If the numerator part is bounded then **Abel**'s theorem can be applied.

Comment: @thevbm thelord Probably I misunderstood your question. My answer was not intended for proof of convergence. It is the result of summation in the convergence domain $|x|<1$.