# Find the sum of $\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty}\frac{n(n+1)}{2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Given the series $$\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty}\frac{n(n+1)}{2^n} = \alpha$$ find $\alpha$.

What technique am I supposed to use here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593996/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If$$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n+1)z^n$$and if$$F(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^{n+1},$$then $F'(z)=f(z)$ and the sum that you're after is $f\left(\frac12\right)$. Now,$$F(z)=z^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^{n-1}=z^2\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n\right)'.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: No, I actually cannot.

Comment: @E.Z. Note that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n=\frac z{1-z}$.

Comment: Okay, I am getting an answer $\alpha=1$, though, it should be $8$.

Comment: @E.Z. What do you get for $F(x)$ and $f(x)$?

Comment: Do I understand correct that $z$ = $\frac{1}{2}$, if so, then I find the derivative of $\frac{z}{1-z}$, multiply it by $z^2$ and let $z = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @E.Z. If you differentiate $\frac z{1-z}$ and then you multiply it by $z^2$, then you'll get $F(z)$. You must differentiate $F$ to get $f$. *Then*, take $z=\frac12$.

Comment: Okay, so I differentiate it two times, which gives $\frac{1/2}{1/16} = 8$. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{n(n+1)}{2^n}=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n(n+1)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$$

then recall that for $|x|<1$

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

$$f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

$$f''(x)=\sum_{k=2}^\infty k(k-1)x^{k-2}=\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}$$

therefore

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty k(k-1)x^{k-2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(k+1)x^{k-1}=\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}\implies\sum_{k=1}^\infty k(k+1)x^{k}=\frac{2x}{(1-x)^3}$$

and then

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n(n+1)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n=\frac{2\frac12}{(1-\frac12)^3}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x) =  \frac{1}{1-x} =\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \Rightarrow xf''(x) = \frac{2x}{(1-x)^3}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n+1)x^n$$
It follows
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n+1)\frac{1}{2^n} =\frac{2\cdot\frac{1}{2}}{(1-\frac{1}{2})^3}= 8$$