# The limit of infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, power-series

I want to know the limit of the series
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^2(1-q)^k,$$
where $0<q<1.$
I have checked from the criterium $a_{k+1}/a_{k} < 1$ that the series converges 
but I don't know hot to compute a limit or an upper bound for this limit?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593996/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-6/594019#594019

Comment: Thanks bhattacharjee! The special case you provided in the link is useful!

Comment: You may simply apply $\left(x\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2$ to $\frac{x}{1-x}$ and evaluate such expression at $x=1-q$.

Comment: [Stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) provide an alternative derivation, based on $\sum_{k\geq 2}\binom{k}{2}x^k = \frac{x^2}{(1-x)^3}$, $\sum_{k\geq 1}\binom{k}{1}x^k = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$ and $k^2=2\binom{k}{2}+\binom{k}{1}$.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in (-1,1)$ and:
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}
$$
Furthermore:
$$
f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)x^k = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}
$$
and
$$
f''(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k^2+k)x^{k-1} = -\frac{2x-2}{(1-x)^4}
$$
Then, your sum is:
$$
(1-q)(f''(1-q)-f'(1-q))
$$

Comment: Thanks Bill O'Haran!