# How can I calculate the sum of $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} n(n+3)x^n$?

Tags: summation

How can I calculate the sum of $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} n(n+3)x^n$ analytically?

Comment: What did you try? I'd start with $n(n+3)x^n=n(n+1)x^n+2nx^n$, then recall $(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593996/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you split your series into two series  using the fact that $$n(n+3) = n(n+1)+2n$$

Then note that derivative of $x^n$ is $nx^{n-1}$ so $$nx^n = x(\frac {d}{dx}(x^n))$$

Then note that the second derivative of $x^{n+1}$ is $n(n+1)x^{n-1}$ and go from there to write your series as some alterations of geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} n(n+3)x^n=x^2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}n(n-1)x^{n-2}+4x\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}=x^2\Bigl(\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}x^n\Bigr)''+4x\Bigl(\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}x^n\Bigr)'$.

Comment: middle should be $4x$ not $3x$

Comment: Oh! yes. It's fixed now. Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score -1):

if $-1< x<1$
$$
\\\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}n(n+3)x^n=x\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(n+3)x^n=x\frac{d}{dx}S(x)
\\S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(n+3)x^n=x\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}n\cdot x^{n-1}+3\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}x^n=
\\=x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}x^n+\frac{3x}{1-x}=x\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x}{1-x}+\frac{3x}{1-x}
=>
\\S(x)=x(\frac{3}{1-x}+\frac{1}{(1-x)^2})=>
\\\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}n(n+3)x^n=x\cdot\frac{d}{dx}S(x)
$$