# Is it a rigorous way to show that $x_n = 1 + {1^2\over 4} + {2^2\over 4^2} + \cdots + {n^2\over 4^n}$ is convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

> Prove the following sequence is convergent: 
>   $$
> x_n = 1 + {1^2\over 4} + {2^2\over 4^2} + \cdots + {n^2\over 4^n}
> $$

I've decided to try Cauchy Criterion here. Consider $|x_m - x_n|$ for $m = 2n > n$:
$$
\begin{align}
|x_m - x_n| &= \left| 1+ \sum_{k=1}^m\frac{k^2}{4^k} - 1 - \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{4^k}\right|\\ 
&= \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{k^2}{4^k}\right| \\
&\stackrel{>0}{=} \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{k^2}{4^k} \\
&\le \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{(2n)^2}{4^k} \\
&\le \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{(2n)^2}{4^{n+1}} \\
&= \frac{4n^3}{4^{n+1}} \\
&= \frac{n^3}{4^n}
\end{align}
$$

Consider the limit:
$$
0 \le \lim_{n\to\infty}|x_{2n} - x_n| \le \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^3}{4^n} = 0
$$

Which by squeeze theorem gives:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_{2n} - x_n| = 0
$$

proving $x_n$ is a fundamental sequence, hence convergent.

I've been also thinking of using monotone convergence theorem:
$$
x_{n+1} - x_n = \frac{(n+1)^2}{4^{n+1}} > 0
$$
By this $x_n$ is monotonically increasing, but i couldn't find an upper bound.

I would like to know two things:

1. It the above a rigorous way to show $x_n$ is convergent?
2. Even though the problem statement only asks to prove convergence rather than find the limit I would still want to find it. W|A suggests its ${20\over 27}$. Is it possible to obtain that result using more or less elementary calculus reasoning?(anything before the definition of a derivative)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593996/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

For $x>4$ we have $$2^x>x^2$$therefore for $n>4$ we obtain $${n^2\over 4^n}<{2^n\over 4^n}={1\over 2^n}$$

Answer (score 2):

Using ratio test: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{(n+1)^2 4^{-(n+1)}}{n^2 4^{-n}}|=\frac{1}{4}<1$$ so the sequence of partial sums is convergent. Furthermore, by considering the geometric series $$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$ $$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}$$ $$f(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n$$

$$\frac{f'(\frac{1}{4})}{4}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^2}{4^{n}}$$ you can easily deduce the limit of the sequence.

Comment: It is just adding a constant and does not depend on $n$, so it should not affect convergence.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{n^2}{4^n}=\frac{1}{2^n}\frac{n^2}{2^n}\leq C\frac{1}{2^n}$ for some constant $C,$ because $\frac{n^2}{2^n}\rightarrow 0$ and hence bounded sequence. So, $\sum_n \frac{n^2}{4^n}\leq C\frac{1}{2^n}<\infty.$