# Calculating $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}x^n$ when $|x|<1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

How do I calculate the sum $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}x^n$$
I know this sum will be finite for $|x|<1$ and will diverge for other values of $x$. Since for other sums it was common to derivate in order to have a sum in the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ I thought it would be a good idea to integrate. However I sill can't solve it. [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20((n%2B1)*(n%2B2)*x%5En%2F(2)%20from%20n%3D0) says the sum is $\frac{-1}{(x-1)^3}$. I would appreciate if someone could guide me to this result.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746388/calculating-1-frac13-frac1-cdot33-cdot6-frac1-cdot3-cdot53-cdot6-cdot

Comment: integrate term by term, twice.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593996/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-6/594019#594019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint:

Calculate $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}x^{n+2}\right)''.$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}{x^{n+2}}$ and differentiate twice. Don’t forget to justify the differentiation under summation.