# If $S= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{2^n} $ then $2S-S$ is

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

I was trying to understand the accepted answer for [How to prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{2^n} = 6$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593996/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-6)
  $$S= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{2^n} $$

> Let $S$ be the given sum.  Then $\displaystyle S = 2S - S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2n+1}{2^n}$.

I can't understand how this works.

Comment: See here -> https://math.stackexchange.com/a/594019/377379

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that$$2S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^2}{2^{n-1}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2}{2^{n-1}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(n+1)^2}{2^n}.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Ah! Yes thanks a lot