# Geometric Summation Question $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)x^{(n-2)} = \frac{2}{(1-x)^3}$

Tags: calculus, summation

My Prof wrote that

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)x^{(n-2)} = \frac{2}{(1-x)^3}$

when $-1< x<1$

I do not understand where the above formula comes from. Can someone please explain the steps or provide a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593996/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the formula $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$. Then take two derivatives.