# Summing a series exactly 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

How does one go about exactly summing this series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nn^2}{3^n}$$

Stuck on this and not sure how to proceed. Appreciate any assistance!

Comment: If the $n^2$ wasn't there, would you know how to solve it? What if we keep the $n$ and remove only the $^2$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593996/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-6

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum\limits^\infty_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{3^n}n^2 = (x\partial_{x})_{|x=1}^2\sum\limits^\infty_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^nx^n}{3^n} = (x\partial_{x})_{|x=1}^2\frac{1}{1+\tfrac{x}{3}}
$$

You should be able to handle the rest...