# How to calculate exact sum of the series? Determine if it converges or diverges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This is the problem:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)}{2^n}$$

How can we write the exact sum of the series and determine if it is converges or not?

Comment: Solution 1: Take two derivatives of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ and evaluate at $x=\frac{1}{2}$. Solution 2: Multiply its partial sums by $\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593996/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-6) is pretty similat.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$
$$(\frac{1}{1-x})''=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)x^{n-2}$$
$$x^2(\frac{1}{1-x})''=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)x^{n}$$
$$\frac{2x^2}{(1-x)^3}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)x^{n}$$
now let $x=\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Convergence is trivial from either the ratio or root tests.

To evaluate the sum, write $f(x):=\sum (x/2)^n=1/(1-x/2)$. Now notice that your sum is $f’’(1)$. In other words take two derivatives of the right side and plug in $x=1$. The answer should be 4.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)x^n=x^2\Bigl(\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)x^{n-2}\Bigr)=x^2\Bigl(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n}\Bigr)^{\!''}.$$

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout: Yes, of course. Sorry for the mistyping. It's fixed now.