# Proof of sum of infinite series including squared variable times a geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, geometric-series

I'm wondering how to prove the following series:

$$\alpha^2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 (1-\alpha)^{(n-1)} = \frac{2-\alpha}{\alpha}$$

Comment: Maybe the downvote was given because you haven't shown your work. If you can, try to elaborate your own solution and add here the details. We'll check that to give some more advice if needed. Good work! Bye

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593996/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-6

Comment: You can also find many worked examples here on MSE. Try to find that also using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to use that for $|x|<1$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n-1)x^{n-2}$$

and some manipulation for geometric series.