# Finding whether $\sum \frac{3n^2+2n}{2^n}$ converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I tried to find a $b_n$ for which $a_n \le b_n$ so I did:

$$\frac{3n^2+2n}{2^n} \le \frac{1}{2^n} \Leftrightarrow \\
3n^2+2n-1 \le 0 \Leftrightarrow \\
(n+1)(3n-1) \le 0 \Leftrightarrow \\
n \le -1 \lor n \le 1/3$$

Since $b_n = (\frac{1}{2})^n$ converges, so does $a_n$ but only for $\{ n: -1 \le n  \le 1/3, n \in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Is this correct? I wrote the set of values for n like that because what I understand is that n has to be a natural number that starts at 1 (or whatever number is given which in this case was one, I don't know how to write with the sum symbol). Still the answer doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. If n has to be a natural number doesn't that set become empty?

Comment: The sum is over all $n$, so bounding the terms for a finite set of $n$ does not say anything about the convergence of the series. Try the ratio test.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3463896/finding-sum-of-series-sum-infty-k-0-frack1k22k/3463901#3463901

Comment: @robjohn I don't understand how a series becomes convergent if it only converges for a certain set of values?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I'm not sure that applies here

Comment: You've shown that the terms of the series are less than $\frac1{2^n}$ for a limited set of $n$, that doesn't say anything about the convergence of the entire series. A different test is needed.

Comment: @robjohn I thought that when you had $a_n \le b_n$ they either both converge or diverge.

Comment: If everything is positive, you have that $a_n\le b_n$, and $\sum b_n$ converges, then $\sum a_n$ converges. The statement you give is not true.

Comment: @robjohn What do you mean by "If everything is positive"?

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire: if some of the terms are negative, the condition that $a_n\le b_n$ will not imply convergence of $\sum a_n$ from the convergence of $\sum b_n$.

Comment: @robjohn I see, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ratio test:
$$\frac{\bigg[\frac{3n^2+8n+5}{2^{n+1}}\bigg]}{\bigg[\frac{3n^2+2n}{2^n}\bigg]}=\frac{3n^2+8n+5}{6n^2+4n}\to\frac12$$

Some clarity:

$2^n$ grows exponentially while $3n^2+2n$ grows quadratically (*much* slower). So, I can tell at a glance the terms will converge, hence I pick the ratio test to illustrate this point

The last part of the statement follows because of what I refer to as "Domination Leads To Irrelevancy", that is:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\bigg[\frac{\sum_{k=0}^m a_k x^k}{\sum_{k=0}^n b_k x^k}\bigg]=\lim_{x\to\infty}\bigg[\frac{a_m}{b_n}x^{m-n}\bigg]=\begin{cases} \frac{a_mb_n}{|a_mb_n|}\infty & m>n \\ \frac{a_m}{b_n} & m=n \\ 0 & m<n \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

$a_n:=\dfrac{3n^2+2n}{2^n} <\dfrac{3n^2+2n^2}{2^n}=$

$\dfrac{5n^2}{2^n}=:b_n.$

Root test for $b_n$:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{5n^2}{2^n}}=1/2<1$, hence convergent.

By comparison test  $\sum a_n$ connnverges.

Used :

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 5^{(1/n)}=1$;

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(n^{(1/n)})^2=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the exponential function grows faster than the all power function, we can write that $3n^2+2n\leq 2^{\frac{n}{2}}$ for large enough $n$. Thus by the comparsion test series converges.