# Determine if power series convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am supposed to determine  the converge field of:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\propto }n^{2}x^{n-1}$$ I do not know how to solve it, because I cannot see the path how to use ration criterion, or Cauchy–Hadamard criterion.

I know that the correct asnwer is $\left ( -1,1 \right )$

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It diverges, What is $x$?

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha I edited my question, can you look at it one more time?

Comment: Ratio test does give the answer. Where exactly is your difficulty?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593996/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-6

Comment: @KaboMurphy Thanks, I just made a foolish mistake

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that radius of convergence = 1/r 
Where r = Lim $a_n^{1/n}$

Here that limit is clearly 1. 
Hence it converges in (-1,1) surely.
Now check -1,1 points explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, they do not belong there