# How to solve this summatory: $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }n^2\:0.999^{n-1}\cdot 0.001$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to solve this summatory?: $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }n^2\:0.999^{n-1}\cdot 0.001$$

I know how to calculate this one: $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }n\:0.999^{n-1}\cdot 0.001$$ as a sumatory of an arithmetic-geometric progression, but I don't know how to calculate this one with the square.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593996/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-6/594019#594019

Answer (score 1):

Call
$$
f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}\;\;,\;|x|<1.
$$
Clearly
$$
f'(x)=\sum_{n\ge1}nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\;\;.
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
f''(x)
&=\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}n(n-1)x^{n-2}\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}n^2x^{n-2}-\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}nx^{n-2}\\
&=\frac1x\left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}n^2x^{n-1}-\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}nx^{n-1}\right)
\end{align*}
from which you get
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}n^2x^{n-1}
&=xf''(x)+\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}nx^{n-1}\\
&=\frac{2x(1-x)}{(1-x)^4}+\frac1{(1-x)^2}\\
&=\frac{1-x^2}{(1-x)^4}.
\end{align*}