# Evaluating the sum $ \sum\limits_{i=0} ^{\infty} \frac{i^{2}}{4^{i}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm reading this book about algorithms and data structures. In the exercise section of chapter 1, there is this sum :

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=0} ^{ \infty} \frac{i^{2}}{4^{i}}$

which we need to evaluate. my solution is the following:

//$S_n$ and $s_t$ are just names

$let: s_n =\displaystyle\sum_{i=0} ^{\infty} \frac{i^{2}}{4^{i}}$

$s_n = 0+\frac{1^{2}}{4^{1}}+\frac{2^{2}}{4^{2}}+\frac{3^{2}}{4^{3}}+\frac{4^{2}}{4^{4}}+\frac{5^{2}}{4^{5}}+....$

$\frac{1}{4}\times s_n = 0+\frac{1^{2}}{4^{2}}+\frac{2^{2}}{4^{3}}+\frac{3^{2}}{4^{4}}+\frac{4^{2}}{4^{5}}+....$

$ s_n - \frac{1}{4}s_n =\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4^{2}}+\frac{5}{4^{3}}+\frac{7}{4^{4}}+....$

$let: s_t = \frac{3}{4^{2}}+\frac{5}{4^{3}}+\frac{7}{4^{4}}+....$

$there for : (1)  
s_n-\frac{1}{4}s_n = \frac{1}{4} + s_t \kern 1pc  and : s_t = \displaystyle\sum_{i= 1}^{\infty} \frac{2i+1}{4^{i+1}}$

$\frac{1}{4}s_t = \frac{3}{4^{3}}+\frac{5}{4^{4}}+\frac{7}{4^{5}}+\frac{9}{4^{5}}+....$

$ s_t-\frac{1}{4} s_t  = \frac{3}{4^{2}}+\frac{2}{4^{3}}+\frac{2}{4^{4}}+\frac{2}{4^{5}}$

$\frac{s_t -1\frac{1}{4}st -\frac{3}{4^{}}}{2} =\frac{1}{4^{3}}+\frac{1}{4^{4}}+\frac{1}{4^{5}}+...$

$(2) \kern 0.5pc\frac{3}{8} st - \frac{3}{32} = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^{n}}$

$now : \displaystyle\sum_{n = 3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^{n}}$ is very easy to evaluate

$\displaystyle\sum_{n = 3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^{n}} = \frac{1}{48}$

using (2) we get:

$\frac{3}{8} st - \frac{3}{32} = \frac{1}{48}$

$\frac{3}{8} st = \frac{1}{48} + \frac{3}{32} $

$st = (\frac{1}{48} + \frac{3}{32}) \times \frac{8}{3}$

using (1) now we get:

$s_n-\frac{1}{4}s_n = \frac{1}{4} + (\frac{1}{48} + \frac{3}{32}) \times \frac{8}{3}$

$s_n = (\frac{1}{4} + (\frac{1}{48} + \frac{3}{32}) \times \frac{8}{3})\times \frac{4}{3}$

$s_n = \frac{73}{256} = 0.28515625$

there for :

$ \displaystyle\sum_{i=0} ^{ \infty} \frac{i^{2}}{4^{i}} =  \frac{73}{256}$

**what do you think??**

Comment: By the way, $0.28515625=\frac{73}{256}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593996/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-6/594019#594019

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number#Identities

Comment: If the series defining $s_t$ starts at $i=0$, you don't have that extra $\frac14$. (Apart from that, I find the name $s_t$ confusing when we already have $s_n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$)

Comment: yeah your right that was a mistake just corrected it and Sn and St are just names