# Power series sum

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Find the radius of convergence and the sum of the series:
$\sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty (2k^2+8k+5)x^k$.
I know how to find the radius of convergence but I have no idea how to calculate the sum of the series.
Where do I begin? Thanks.

Comment: If you have found the radius of convergence, why don't you add that to the question?

Comment: Try differentiating the power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k = \frac1{1-x}$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593996/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-6/594019#594019

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

For example,

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\,,\,\,|x|<1\implies f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1}\implies f''(x)=\sum_{k=2}^\infty k(k-1)x^{k-2}\implies$$

$$f''(x)=\sum_{k=2}^\infty k^2x^{k-2}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1}$$

but we know

$$f(x)=\frac1{1-x}\implies f'(x)=\frac1{(1-x)^2}\;\;\ldots\text{ and etc.}$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

You can rewrite the sums as
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty 8k x^{k}&=8x\sum_{k=0}^\infty k x^{k-1},\\[1ex]
\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2k^2x^k&=2x^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)x^{k-2}+2x\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^{k-1},
\end{align} whence
$$\sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty (2k^2+8k+5)x^k=2x^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty k(k-1)x^{k-2}+10x\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^{k-1}+5\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{k}.$$