# The sum of the series(in functional series)

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, divergent-series

The task is to find the sum of the series:

[image]

I can calculate the sum of an ordinary positive number series, but as I understand it, this series is not an ordinary positive number series. Tell me how to calculate the sum of such series

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What is an “ordinary positive number series”? How is this related to Fourier series?

Comment: I meant positive series

Comment: Many similar questions have already been answered here.

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3950025/42969 for a very similar question.

Comment: But I don't understand their answers. I did not understand why they got such answers and I decided to ask my own question.

Comment: Then I suggest that you tell us which answers you have seen, and what you do not understand about them. Otherwise the question might get closed as a duplicate, or as off-topic (no context given), or you might get another answer which you do not understand.

Comment: Let's say the example from the link above, I don't understand why he expanded the series like that. How he in the first and in the second pulls out $8x$ or $2x^2$