# If $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^k$ = 30, compute x.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

If $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^k$ = 30, compute x. 
I don't think I can find $x$ because using $a/(1-r)$ is only one equation for two variables.

Looking it up on wolfram alpha, it says $x/(x-1)^2$ when $|x| < 1$. Can someone explain to me please?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593996/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-6/594019#594019

Comment: Compute the sum in terms of $x$, or compute the sum of $x^k$, differentiate and make appropriate adjustments. Note that if $|x| \ge 1$ the sum does not converge.

Comment: I'm in precalc, I don't think I'm supposed to differentiate.

Comment: Writing $f(x):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^k$, look at $f(x)-xf(x)$.

Comment: @EdmundChang As far as I know differentiation is part of precalculus. During my school time the topic `series` comes far behind `differentiation`.

Comment: Closely related is [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732). Some of the answers use calculus, but there are still quite a few that don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can observe what happens to the summation when you expand the first terms:

$$
\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} kx^k  =
1(x) + 2(x^2) + 3(x^3) + \dots
$$

This can be rearranged in a way that will yield in a sum of geometric series:
$$
1(x) + 2(x^2) + 3(x^3) ... =
x + (x^2 + x^2) + (x^3 + x^3 + x^3) + \dots
$$

Now observe what taking the first element of each term, you have a geometric series that starts a $x^1$.

But starting from the second term, taking the second element from all terms you also have a geometric series that starts on $x^2$.

So you actually have a sum of series, each one starting at plus one higher coefficient.

$$
\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} kx^k = \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\sum^{\infty}_{j=k} x^j
$$

Now you can solve the first summation: $a_0 = x^k$, then:
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{j=k} x^j = \frac{x^k}{1-x}
$$

Now solve the second summation:

$$
\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{x^k}{1-x} = \frac{1}{1-x}\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}{x^k} = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^k=x\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k-1}=x\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{k}\right)'$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^k = 30 \implies \frac{x}{(x - 1)^2} = 30\quad\text{ for}\quad |x|<1\quad\implies\quad x=\frac{5}{6}$$